# css @import relative to the HTML documents it's linked to?

Tags: html, css, http, url, server

I'm curious if it's possible to link an HTML document to a CSS file at an absolute path, then the linked stylesheet @imports a CSS file located in a folder relative to the HTML file?

Something like:

```
 @import url("window.location../../custom.css");
```

No particular use case in mind.  Just curiosity.

Comment: I don't think you can put javascript inside a url

Answer (score 0):

`../../custom.css` should do it.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, that will load a css file relative to the css file, no?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, You should use javascript instead of css.

e.g.

```
<script>
    var css = document.createElement("link");
    css.type = "text/css";
    css.rel = "stylesheet";
    css.href = "../../custom.css";
    document.head.appendChild(css);
</script>
```

Comment: Nice.  By sheer fluke, I noticed this in my subscription feed shortly after posting this question.  [CSS and the Critical Path](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0Fk85to6hA).  Web development is about to reach a whole new level...